# Android get value from ArrayList

Tags: android, listview

The overall idea is to change the background of a TextView in a ListView based on the value that is put into it.

E.g. if the value entered is true, then the colour changes.

however I having trouble getting the specific value rather than the string

Here is my controller

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllSkills () {
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "getAll");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "characterSkills";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("skillId", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("skillName", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("ability", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("rank", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("enabled", cursor.getString(4));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordList;
}
```

Which is being called by this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> characterSkills = controller
            .getAllSkills();

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CharacterSheet.this,
            characterSkills, R.layout.dd_skill_entry, new String[] {
                    "skillId", "skillName", "ability", "rank", "enabled" }, 
            new int[] { R.id.skillid, R.id.skillname, R.id.ability,
                    R.id.rank, R.id.enabled });


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + characterSkills.get(4), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The toast returns the entire hashmap at that location rather than the "enabled" value that I want.

So my question is how do I get this value and how do I check its true and if it is change the background colour of the specific Views (R.id.enabled) it is entered into.

Comment: i think for changing background color of the specific Views you will need to create custom Adapter instead of using default

Comment: why do you have a `HashMap` inside an `ArrayList`? In any case, you first need to access the specific `HashMap` within the `ArrayList`'s, and then get the specific value from the `HashMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best things to do is create a POJO like

```
public class CharacterSkills {

private long skillId; 
private String skillName; 
private boolean enabled;

// TODO : make getters/setters

}
```

and then used this POJO in your function. Stuff like this :

```
public List<CharacterSkills> getAllSkills () {
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "getAll");
    List<CharacterSkills> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<CharacterSkills>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "characterSkills";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            CharacterSkills character = new CharacterSkills();
            character.setSkillId(cursor.getLong(0));
            character.setSkillName(cursor.getString(1));
            character.setEnabled(cursor.getInt(2) == 1 ? true : false);  // there is no boolean in SQLite
            // TODO : all informations about character 

            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return wordList;
}
```

Then you will use a custom adapter

```
public class CharacterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<CharacterSkills> characters;

    public CharacterAdapter(List<CharacterSkills> characters) {
        this.characters = characters;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return characters.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharacterSkills getItem(int position) {
        return characters.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // You can use ViewHolder pattern to optimize your listview 
        convertView = LayoutInfalter.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.dd_skill_entry, null);
        TextView myCharacter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.enabled);
        CharacterSkills character = characters.get(position);
        // TODO : define your background
        if (character.isEnabled()) {
             myCharacter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourdrawableenable);
        } else {
             myCharacter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourdrawabledisable);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And finally, you can use your own adapter.

```
List<CharacterSkills> characters = controller.getAllSkills();
CharacterAdapter adapter = new CharacterAdapter(characters);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```